# 'str' object is not callable in NLTK

Tags: python, python-2.7, nlp, nltk, nltk-book

```
import re
import nltk
import pandas as pd
from nltk.chunk import RegexpParser
from textblob import TextBlob
data = open('data.txt', 'r')
data = data.read()

# region Fetch Account Type
chunkData = r"""DataChunk: {(<NNP><NNP>+<CD>+)}
  }<JJ|IN|DT|TO>+{"""



lines = [line for line in open('data.txt')]
lstLines=data.split('|')
dataLines=[]
for lines in lstLines:
    dataLines=lines.split("\n")

for line in dataLines:
    if 'Data' in line:
        DataTags = TextBlob(line).tags
        Datachunker = RegexpParser(chunkData)
        Datachunked = Datachunker.parse(DataTags)

        for chunk in Datachunked:

                if type(chunk) == nltk.tree.Tree and chunk.label() == "DataChunk":
                    DatachunkedLst = chunk.leaves()
                    Datachunked = [leaf[0] for leaf in DatachunkedLst if leaf[1] == 'CD']
                    Data = '/'.join(Datachunked)
```

> Error:if type(chunk) == nltk.tree.Tree and chunk.label() == "DataChunk":
>   TypeError: 'str' object is not callable

However i am able to print `chunk.label()`

Comment: Hello Vinay, Please consider writing what you are trying to achieve. Otherwise we can only guess.

Comment: please provide some data you are reading from data.txt file

Comment: Did you, by any chance, assign a string value to a variable named `type`? Such as `type = "concept-free"`?

Comment: It was working an hour ago...But i am able to print chunk.label too.But the moment the interpretor tries to execute if condition,it says its not chunk.label is not callable . I am trying to get named entites of Nouns and integers using chunking

Comment: Oh, have you tried `chunk.label` (without the parentheses) instead?

Comment: (DataChunk Code/NNP No/NNP 91022910914/CD 0/CD)
<bound method Tree.label of Tree('DataChunk', [('Code', u'NNP'), ('No', u'NNP'), ('91022910914', u'CD'), ('0', u'CD')])>

Comment: I am able to print chunk,and chunk.label() as well as chunk.label

Comment: if  chunk.label() == "DataChunk":
                    DatachunkedLst = chunk.leaves()
 

when i run this, it shows AttributeError: 'tuple' object has no attribute 'label'

Comment: What does `print(type)` give you? Just before the `if` statement?

Comment: it doesnt print anything

Comment: Then that's the source of the problem: it should print `<class 'type'>`. As pointed out in my answer, the variable `type` is probably assigned a string value – might be the empty string or some blank characters, if it prints as nothing.

Comment: Yes. Got it . Thanks i assigned type as string

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I suspect that the following is happening:

Somewhere in your code – it's not included in your snippet, though – you assign a string value to a variable called `type`, eg.:

```
type = "context-free"
```

This gives exactly your error message:

```
>>> type = "context-free"
>>> type(object())
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
TypeError: 'str' object is not callable
```

I think it's quite likely that this is happening here; at least it frequently occurs to me that I want to store some kind of "type" in a variable, but I usually refrain from that because of the kind of trouble you see here.

One way to avoid bugs like that is using a linter: A tool that is run in the background by your editor, checking your code and spotting dangerous stuff just like this. I highly recommend you try one!

Comment: But chunk is not string man ,Before checking if conditon

Comment: I never said `chunk` is a string (or a "string man", whatever that be). I'm talking about the built-in function `type`, which can be overriden.